# how to use sequence in oracle insert Select for group of rows

Tags: oracle, plsql

We have this existing design in production and can't change anything at the table level as it requires approvals.

Oracle Version - Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

And we have test server with Oracle Database Release 19.0.0.0.0 as well currently certifying it, and need the solution for both versions.

My Source table will have

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3
------------------
1    | A    | 1   
1    | A    | 2   
1    | A    | 3   
2    | B    | 4   
2    | B    | 1   
2    | B    | 5
```

My expected output

```
seq_val | COL1 | COL2 | COL3
-------------------------
100  | 1    | A    | 1   
100  | 1    | A    | 2   
100  | 1    | A    | 3   
101  | 2    | B    | 4   
101  | 2    | B    | 1   
101  | 2    | B    | 5
```

I have to use an existing sequence to output the value for seq_val column asuming the next value at 100. A new seq_val to be generated for the group of COl1 and Col2

TIA

Comment: seq_val column changes according COL1 value?

Comment: @alvalongo, For Col1 and Col2, Sorry missed to mention it.